# How Does ssh-agent Select a Key if There's a set?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

When using `ssh` together with `ssh-agent` which keeps a set of keys what is the flow to select the right key.
Is it `ssh` who requests the set of keys and iterates over them or `ssh-agent` produces the iterations it self?

In my case I'm using `git` on a private repo which is authorized over `ssh` with non default key (other then `id_rsa`). So if `ssh-agent` holds solely the desired key the `git` operates with the repo pretty good.

But when both `id_rsa` and `repo_rsa` added to `ssh-agent` (in any order) the repo isn't authorized.

So who is in the `git`-`ssh`-`ssh-agent` chain responsible for the selection of the right key?

And is it possible to adjust the selection just on the `ssh-agent` level without pollution of `.ssh/config` with mapping fake host names to identities. So that to keep the repo urls clean and leave the key selection just "under" the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`?

Answer (score 0):

> So who is in the `git`-`ssh`-`ssh-agent` chain responsible for the selection of the right key?

Both ssh and ssh-agent.  Git plays no part here.  Ssh is ultimately responsible for *trying* the keys, so it has the ultimate responsibility.  It is however plausible that, after requesting keys *from* the agent, ssh would try them in the order the agent handed them over, or perhaps the reverse of that order; and of course ssh-agent could (somehow) be instructed to hand over only the *right one* (perhaps via careful `ssh-add -d` use).

> And is it possible to adjust the selection just on the ssh-agent level without pollution of `.ssh/config` with mapping fake host names to identities[?]

Apart from my not-entirely-serious `ssh-add -d` suggestion, I don't believe so, but I'm not an ssh expert.